# 'make' fails when installing ssh2 with MAMP

Tags: php, macos, mamp, pecl

I'm trying to install the ssh2 package but it invariably fails with this error:

```
make: *** [ssh2.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

I've tried `pecl install ssh2-0.11.3` as well as downloading the package and trying to compile manually, but I always wind up with the same error.

I'm using MAMP Pro 2.0.5 on Mac OS X 10.7 with PHP 5.3.6. Googling around, I've found a handful of suggestions, but they all seem to refer to older versions of the package, referring to bugs that have already been fixed.

Any suggestions on where I can try looking to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you don't have a compiler.

If you do not have Xcode installed, try installing this and try again. This will give you the most common compiling tools.

Comment: @shanebonham Did you find a solution for this in the end? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @alsobubbly Sorry, I barely remember last week, let alone 5 years ago :)

Comment: @shanebonham no problem, thank you for your response. I figured it out in the end, my Xcode was out of date but wasn't showing the update in the App Store so had to re-install it. :)